# Ignoring a substring if it comes before another substring

Tags: python

I have a string and am looking for two substrings and want to display what is in between those two substrings. But I want to find substring 1 before substring 2. How can I ignore substring 2 until I have found substring 1? The problem I am having is if subString2 comes before substring1 it returns an empty list.

```
def findMiddle(mainString, subString1, subString2):
 
    newString = []
    startPos = mainString.find(subString1)
    endPos = mainString.find(subString2)
        
    for i in range(startPos, endPos):
            newString.append(i)
            
    return newString
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a community focused on helping each other. Congrats on posting your first question. Can you please share a sample of your desired output so we can know what you are looking for. The solution seems easy but want to ensure we got your question correctly.

Comment: Find substring 1. Then from that position + len of substring, search for substring 2. The string in between is what you want. If I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Do you mean to return a list of integers or the actual text you found?  You can replace the for loop with newstring= mainString[startPos:endPos]

Answer (score 2):

don't search the whole string for the end position search only the slice of the string after the start position.

```
startPos = mainString.find(subString1)
endPos = startPos+mainString[startPos:].find(subString2)
```

Comment: OMG!!!!!!! I have been staring at this for hours, I cant believe how simple it was. Thank you!!

Comment: Note you have to add startpos onto mainpos first, to get the correct index.

Comment: also Note that this fixes the problem in the question but returns a list of indices of the characters between start and end, it doesn't return the text itself.

Comment: When iterating over something and just add its elements directly to something else, you can avoid the for-loop, just use a `list` constructor : `return list(range(startPos, endPos))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def middle(line: str, word1: str, word2: str) -> str:
    i = line.find(word1)
    if i >= 0:
        j = line.find(word2, i + len(word1))
        if j > i:
            return line[i + len(word1):j].strip()
    return None

print(middle("a b c", "a", "c"))
print(middle("c b a", "a", "c"))
```

> b
>
> None

Comment: shouldn't the response for `print(middle("a b c", "b", "c"))` be None?

Comment: @JoeFerndz No. `b` and `c` are found and what exists between them is an empty string.  empty string is not `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full code to help you understand where you went wrong. I am leaving the return function for you to decipher. It is easy for you to figure out. Let me know if you find it difficult.

The index is important when you search for a string. Also, you need to check for conditions when the first string is not found but second string is found. Remember find method will return -1 if the string is not found. You need to check for that before you check for the next string.

```
mainString = 'Happy Thanksgiving to everyone this morning'
subString1 = 'Thanks'
subString2 = 'is'
def findMiddle(mainString, subString1, subString2):
    x = mainString.find(subString1)
    if x < 0:
        print (subString1, 'does not exist in', mainString)
        return
    ln = len(subString1)
    y = mainString.find(subString2,x+ln)
    if y < 0: 
        print (subString2, 'does not exist in', mainString, 'after', subString1)

    elif y == x+ln:
        #find result will always be pos of string 
        #irrespective of where you start from. 
        #So you need to check if pos is after previous find

        print ('No strings exist in', mainString, 'between', subString1, 'and', subString2)

    else:
        print ('The middle string between',subString1,'and',subString2, ':',mainString[x+ln:y])


findMiddle(mainString, subString1, subString2)
```

The outputs from the program are as follows:

Example 1:

```
mainString = 'Happy Thanksgiving to everyone this morning'
subString1 = 'Thanks'
subString2 = 'is'
```

Output:

```
The middle string between Thanks and is : giving to everyone th
```

Example 2:

```
mainString = 'Happy Thanksgiving to everyone this morning'
subString1 = 'Thaxks'
subString2 = 'is'
```

Output:

```
Thaxks does not exist in Happy Thanksgiving to everyone this morning
```

Example 3:

```
mainString = 'Happy Thanksgiving to everyone this morning'
subString1 = 'Thanks'
subString2 = 'ix'
```

Output:

```
ix does not exist in Happy Thanksgiving to everyone this morning after Thanks
```

Example 4:

```
mainString = 'Happy Thanksgiving to everyone this morning'
subString1 = 'Thanks'
subString2 = 'Happy'
```

Output:

```
Happy does not exist in Happy Thanksgiving to everyone this morning after Thanks
```

Example 5:

```
mainString = 'Happy Thanksgiving to everyone this morning'
subString1 = 'Thanks'
subString2 = 'giv'
```

Output:

```
No strings exist in Happy Thanksgiving to everyone this morning between Thanks and giv
```

Comment: not sure why the response was down voted. I did provide the full explanation. However, I did leave the OP to figure out the return solution. That will help the OP to understand the code better.

Answer (score -1):

```
def findMiddle(mainString, subString1, subString2):
    startPos = mainString.find(subString1)
    endPos = mainString.find(subString2)
    if startPos==endPos:
        endPos = mainString[startPos+1:].find(subString2)
        newString = mainString[startPos+len(subString1):endPos+len(subString2)]
    elif startPos<endPos:
        newString = mainString[startPos:endPos+len(subString2)]
    else:
        newString = mainString[endPos:startPos+len(subString1)]
    return newString
```

This is rough, hope it works [edited]

Comment: That has the same problem that OP describes

Comment: looks like everyone is making the same mistake. Once you find subString1, then you need to add the length of subString1 to start looking for subString2. Dont forget to advance the index before you start searching.

Comment: @JoeFerndz the question is not detailed. I will edit now

Comment: @JoeFerndz Check it now huh

Comment: Let me check on it

Comment: @JeffUK It won't because there are no words in between

Comment: This fails if substring1 = '{' and substring2 = '}' and mainstring = "}{FINDTHISSTRING}"